# How to get specific a word with Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I want to get `INFO`,`ERROR`,`DEBUG`  with one Regular Expression.

Eg，when meet `1`,will get `INFO`; when meet `2`,will get `ERROR`;when meet `3`,will get `DEBUG`.

```
 1. [0;39m [http-nio-9000-exec-1] 2017-09-13 17:52:45,394 [34m|-INFO [0;39m [1;30mWatchHandlerInterceptor.java:59[0;39m [1;31m[0;39m |    [35mreq monitor

 2. [0;39m [http-nio-9000-exec-1] 2017-09-13 17:52:45,394 [34m|-ERROR[0;39m [1;30mWatchHandlerInterceptor.java:59[0;39m [1;31m[0;39m |    [35mreq monitor 

 3. [0;39m [http-nio-9000-exec-1] 2017-09-13 17:52:45,394 [34m|- DEBUG[0;39m [1;30mWatchHandlerInterceptor.java:59[0;39m [1;31m[0;39m |    [35mreq monitor
```

please show the regex

Comment: what do mean by meet "1" ? didn't get you

Comment: "1" means  [0;39m [http-nio-9000-exec-1] 2017-09-13 17:52:45,394 [34m|-INFO [0;39m [1;30mWatchHandlerInterceptor.java:59[0;39m [1;31m[0;39m |    [35mreq monitor;


"2" means  [0;39m [http-nio-9000-exec-1] 2017-09-13 17:52:45,394 [34m|-ERROR[0;39m [1;30mWatchHandlerInterceptor.java:59[0;39m [1;31m[0;39m |    [35mreq monitor ;


"3" means  [0;39m [http-nio-9000-exec-1] 2017-09-13 17:52:45,394 [34m|- DEBUG[0;39m [1;30mWatchHandlerInterceptor.java:59[0;39m [1;31m[0;39m |    [35mreq monitor;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your regular expression:

```
/\b(info|debug|error)\b/ig
```

Comment: The `g` modifier is not necessary.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer updated regex, now it'll match exact word only.